# VB.Net app won't launch klist.exe executable (even from full path)

Tags: vb.net, klist

Have a VB.Net app wherein I am trying to call klist.exe to purge cached Kerberos tickets.

```
Dim klist As New ProcessStartInfo("C:\Windows\System32\klist.exe")
klist.Arguments = "purge"
Process.Start(klist)
```

Debugger spits out:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The system cannot find the file specified'
```

The file *clearly* exists, and can be run *without* elevated permissions from a command prompt.

What kind of tomfoolery is this? Or am I so tired I'm missing something obvious?

Comment: Is you app run as a 32bit or 64bit process? Check the `SysWOW64` directory.

Comment: Read about [File System Redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - your app is being redirected to a folder where klist is not present. On my PC I need to untick "prefer 32bit" in the Compile tab of project settings in order to launch klist.exe

Comment: 32 vs 64 for Target CPU doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Wrong... Setting target to 64-bit fixed it. I assumed (and we *all* know about doing *that*...) that VS was already kicking out 64-bit files. It wasn't, and now issue is fixed. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: Just a SO tip:: you should put your solution as an answer, and then mark it as Accepted, so others don't have to read through the comments. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a 64bit machine, the files in `c:\windows\system32` are 64bit files and the files in `c:\windows\SysWOW64` are 32bit files (yeah.. I know what you're going to say). A background redirection in the OS ensures that 32bit programs that try to access `c:\windows\system32` are redirected to `c:\windows\syswow64` so they can find the 32bit files they think they want out of system32. Given that `klist.exe` is in system32 and hence 64bit (for me at least, ymmv), your app not finding it means it's likely it is 32bit and being redirected to the syswow64 folder, which doesn't contain klist.exe. Your console session, on the other hand, doesn't have this bitness problem and is using the system32 folder/finding klist.exe

Set your app to be 64bit; set the Target CPU to `x64` or make it AnyCPU and turn off the "Prefer 32bit" tickbox